# NEO4J Cypher query START index query with multiple nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to write an cypher query that can START with an exact index query for multiple nodes?

For example:

```
START n=node:indexName (key="value1", key="value2" ...)
```

I was unable to achieve something like the above, I am about to explore whether this can be done with a lucene query.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634179/querying-with-an-in-clause-using-the-index-in-neo4j-with-cypher

Answer (score 5):

I just asked a very similar question:

[querying with an "IN" clause using the index in neo4j with Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634179/querying-with-an-in-clause-using-the-index-in-neo4j-with-cypher)

And Peter answered with the following

```
start n = node:indexName('key:123 OR key:456')
```

Comment: Thanks, a lucene query would work. Although something else struck me as a possibility, if the same field that is indexed is also a property of the node, I wounder if its possible to do something like 'WHERE node.property IN collection'

Comment: Yes, you can do that, it will look at the node properties instead of taking help of an index (although that might change with better indexing and query optimization later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
START thing1 = node:topic('name:(keyword1)'), thing2 = node:topic('name:(keyword2)')
```

it will look for two topics, containing each a different value;

```
start n=node:topic('name:(keyword1 AND keyword2)') return n
```

it will look for multiple keywords in the same node