# querying with an "IN" clause using the index in neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to use my auto_index in neo4j and pass in an array of strings to match against.  I know that you can add an IN clause to the end of your cypher query but that doesn't use the indexes and I'm assuming will do a database scan of all the records.  What's the best way to do this with an index query?

e.g. Get me users whose facebookId is in ["123", "456", "789"] assuming there is an auto_index on facebookId and there are 1 million user nodes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose this is worth posting as an answer:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('facebookId:("123", "456", "789")')
...
```

Example:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/3mcvr5

Comment: For the record, limited to 512 fields with the current Neo 1.9.M04. (which I think uses Lucene 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

You would do this query by having an explicit index lookup, like

```
start user = node:node_auto_index('facebookId:123 OR facebookId:456') match  ...
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/nj98lt for an example.

Comment: I suppose that'll work, but it might get very long if I have 20 or 30 ids to match against.  No other cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: BTW where is the documentation on what operators and parameters can be passed in the index query in cypher?

Comment: Most of the stuff is in here. It's passed directly to Lucene for the default indexes: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Overview

Comment: `OR` is the default, btw: http://console.neo4j.org/r/cwqhmy provides the same results without explicitly stating `OR` (just FYI)